# spring boot api return 404 Not Found time to time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

**It is normal to use most of the time, and 404 appears occasionally. I don’t know how to locate the problem.**

controller file:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @GetMapping("info")
    public Result info(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap = authService.getInfo(token);

        return ResultGenerator.success(stringObjectMap);
    }
}
```

GET: localhost:9000/v1/auth/info?token=gNGLJLLZsluDsIQw This ERROR MESSAGE is displaying time to time:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-29T06:46:35.477+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/auth/info"
}
```

version info:

- spring boot: 2.2.6.RELEASE
- spring cloud: Hoxton.SR1

**Append：**

spring cloud gateway yml config:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    nacos:
      discovery:
        server-addr: localhost:8848
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          "[/**]":
            allowCredentials: true
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Content-Length, TOKEN, Authorization"
            allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
            maxAge: 3628800
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      routes:
        - id: auth-service
          uri: lb://auth-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/auth/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
        - id: bus-service
          uri: lb://bus-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
```

**Solution to be verified**

I used the zipkin, found the route /v1/auth/info matched to `bus-service(/v1/**)`, so return 404 not found.

From this to the conclusion：**The writing order of the route does not guarantee its matching priority. So must add `order` configuration.**

Comment: I suppose the problem is not with this controller. Please show your spring cloud code

Comment: @DmitriyPankratov I added the yml config of the gateway

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `@RequestMapping("/auth")` and replacing `@GetMapping("info")` to look like below:

```
@GetMapping("auth/info")
public Result info(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
    Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap = authService.getInfo(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add / before info like this

```
 @GetMapping("/info")
    public Result info(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap = authService.getInfo(token);

        return ResultGenerator.success(stringObjectMap);
    }
```

Since you are using @RequestParam, you need to pass value like this

localhost:9000/auth/info?token="token_value"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add in this question. I updated this question

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

> If the url has a lb scheme (ie lb://myservice), it will use the Spring
> Cloud LoadBalancerClient to resolve the name (myservice in the
> previous example) to an actual host and port and replace the URI in
> the same attribute.
>
> By default when a service instance **cannot be found** in the LoadBalancer
> a 503 will be returned. You can configure the Gateway **to return a 404**
> by setting spring.cloud.gateway.loadbalancer.use404=true.

You can also try to specify an **order** in routes list:

```
routes:
  - id: auth-service
    uri: lb://auth-service
    order: 0
    predicates:
      - Path=/v1/auth/**
    filters:
      - StripPrefix=1
  - id: bus-service
    uri: lb://bus-service
    order: 1
    predicates:
      - Path=/v1/**
    filters:
      - StripPrefix=1
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer inspired me. I may have found the problem